# How can I use CSS to make a uniform underline within an anchor superscript text?

Tags: html, css, anchor, underline, superscript

I did not find any solution do this question: 
How can I use CSS to make a uniform underline within an anchor superscript text?

But it is solved on your "[Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)" page, when we fill it. How did you do that

Example:
[February 17th, 2011](http://earthquake-report.com/2011/02/17/earthquakes-list-february-17-2011/)
    [February 17<sup>th</sup>, 2011](http://earthquake-report.com/2011/02/17/earthquakes-list-february-17-2011/)

In Internet Explorer the th cause the underline to follow up; how can I make it consistent like it behave in Ms-Word, one continuous line even under the th.

The closest answer I found is not conclusive; the underline still breaks across the link which is what I'm trying to solve to. [Superscript underline in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420770/superscript-underline-in-ie)
Even this one did not answer it but at lest give me reason to think out of the box:
[Superscript in CSS only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501671/superscript-in-css-only)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a `border-bottom: 1px solid black;` would work? I'm not getting this style degradation in Safari/Chrome.

Also, try adding some padding: `padding-bottom: 5px;`. Maybe one of these would work.

Good luck?

Comment: Ok thanks, I would prefer to find a way to deal whit the underline.

Comment: even with "text-decoration: none;" it still do not look like a link

Comment: Here is a simple of the code: <a href="http://earthquake-report.com/2011/02/17/earthquakes-list-february-17-2011/">February 17<sup>th</sup>, 2011</a> to help