# Superscript in anchor tag is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, .net

I have a link and a superscript in the link name. I get the superscript but it moved top with the underline as it is a link. 
i am trying to keep the underline in the place with the title and just raise the superscript only but running out of ideas.

i tried one trick but it works only in google chrome.

here is my code

```
   <A href="http://www.google.com/" target=_blank>Google<SUP style="BORDER-BOTTOM: white 1px solid; COLOR: white !important">®</SUP> search</A>
```

here is jsfiddle link 
https://jsfiddle.net/f582kmsj/

Comment: Suppose you tried something like the solution here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420770/superscript-underline-in-ie

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use inline styles, this will give you a single continuous underline:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Google<sup style="display: inline-block; border-bottom: 1px solid; padding-bottom: 4px">®</sup> search</a>
```

Or as a CSS declaration:

```
a > sup {
  display: inline-block; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid; 
  padding-bottom: 4px
}
```

You may need to adjust the bottom padding according to your text size.

Comment: I ended up leaving the superscript along with the underline. So the superscript has the underline text and the underline just below it is empty. Sorry to say but none of the solutions solved my problem. We need to keep the anchor underline that is the requirement and still need superscript. So till now we are living with the problem till we find another solutions. Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 1):

remove border from the sup element and add this to your styles:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

By not specifying a color on the border, it will always match the color of the text and more-or-less mimic the default underline.