# Sup element weird text-decoration in anchor tag

Tags: html, css

We recently found out that when there's a sup element in an anchor tag, the text-decoration looks weird when it's set to underline. It looks like this:
[image: Current state]

If it helps, this is the structure of our HTML:

```
<li>
  <a>
    <p>Some Text
      <span>
        <sup>
          <span>
            <strong>®</strong>
          </span>
        </sup>
      </span>
    </p>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Why so many spans?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Superscript in anchor tag is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350077/superscript-in-anchor-tag-is-not-working-properly)

Comment: `Some Text ®`, This is what I'm getting for the code you shared.

Comment: @Laif - That's what our rich text editor renderer is spitting out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this happened to me, I went this route. Remove the default underline, and add a border below the content.

```css
p {
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom:1px solid #0001EE;
  padding-bottom:0px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: unset;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <p>Some Text
      <span>
        <sup>
          <span>
            <strong>®</strong>
          </span>
        </sup>
      </span>
    </p>
  </a>
</li>
```